# Time at which there have been more people in a session

Tags: statistics, optimization, maxima-minima, data-analysis

Let's say I have a document with all data of a Zoom (or whatever platform for online classes and conferences) session that gives me the following for each person in the session:

- The time at which they have joined it.
- How much time they have spent in the session until leaving.

My question is: given only this information, how can I find (if I can) the time/interval of hours at which there have been more people in the session?

I would really appreciate any kind of help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You know the times when people entered and left.  Sort each of these lists in increasing order.  The number of people in the session at time $t$ is the difference between the number of entering times $\le t$ and the number of leaving times $< t$.  Compute this for all the entering times and see which
makes this largest.  The interval you want is from that entering time until the next leaving time.  Of course there may be ties, so there could be several such intervals.